# Simultaneous loading of same source HTML5 video fails?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple test page here:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Event "seeked" test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main" align="center"></div>
        <script>
            var main = document.getElementById("main");
            var thumbnails = document.getElementById("thumbnails");

            var video = document.createElement("video");
            video.setAttribute("id", "video");
            video.setAttribute("src", "pathtomyvideo.mp4");
            video.setAttribute("controls", "true");
            video.setAttribute("autoplay", "true");
            main.appendChild(video);

            var video2 = document.createElement("video");
            video2.setAttribute("id", "video2");
            video.setAttribute("src", "pathtomyvideo.mp4");
            video2.setAttribute("controls", "true");
            video2.setAttribute("autoplay", "true");
            main.appendChild(video2);        
        </script>        
      </body>
</html>
```

In Chrome, only a single Video file loads while the other does not appear to load. When the two sources are different it loads fine. If I explicitly type out the HTML only one of them loads an the other does not (same behavior).

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Do you experience the same behaviuor if you type the HTML explicitly?

Comment: Same behavior if typed explicitly.

Comment: Try adding `?something`to one of the src-attributes and see if this is different enough for Chrome to treat them as different sources

Comment: Just did, no change. Good suggestion though.

Comment: I guess another obvious soultion is making a duplicate of the file on the server and reference the other one in `video2`.

Comment: What causes this behaviour in Chrome, however, I have no clue about.

Comment: @mariusnn an obvious solution, but one I would prefer to avoid if possible being a silly waste of space

Comment: Agreed. I guess some kind of script doing redirects etc could be another workaround. Someone else with more in-dept experince with this will hopefully be able to think straight in the morning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to kick yourself over this one, you have copied and pasted no doubt? The second video src is not set, you merely overwrite the first:

```
video.setAttribute("src", "pathtomyvideo.mp4");
```

Change to

```
video2.setAttribute("src", "pathtomyvideo.mp4");
```

Just tested and works like a charm...